# What is the recommended way to install a .NET Core application on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, installation

Typically, we would use third party software installers such as `InnoSetup` for a `Windows` platform (which is not available for Linux).

What installers could be used to deploy/install `.NET Core` applications to a `Linux` platform? Are there any installers for Linux or I should simply use a `.makefile` or create a `tar`?

Comment: The options available to you will depend on your target distribution of Linux. Which distro are you using and how familiar are you with Linux?

Comment: You _could_ tar.gz the result of a `dotnet publish -c release` and un-tar.gz is when it's on the target machine. You _could_ create a script to pull the code and build on the target machine. You _could_ use FTP to push the code to the target machine. These aren't the only options, and they'll be far from optimal (depending on your situation).

Comment: @JamieTaylor current target is Ubuntu. I have looked into the tar option as well, and will test out this concept. Current situation is we need some type of method, where we can give the customer an "installer" so they can run it on an Ubuntu machine. FTP will not work, as we are targeting an offline approach. thanks for the tips